# Apex Test - Static methods cannot be invoked through an object instance: getChecks()

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm new to Salesforce and I was wondering why do I get the following error for my code. if you can please write me back code would be gratefully appreciated.

**API class**

```
public class CheckbookAPI {

    // DigitalCheck__APIConfig__c is a custom setting object that stores the API Keys
    public static DigitalCheck__APIConfig__c Config = DigitalCheck__APIConfig__c.getOrgDefaults();

    public CheckbookAPI()
    {
    }

    public static String getChecks() {
        HttpRequest req = CheckbookAPI.getHttpRequest('GET', '/transactions');
        return CheckbookAPI.getHttpResponse(req);
    }    
    public static String createCheck(String email, Decimal amount, String firstName, String lastName, String semail, String description) {
        HttpRequest req = CheckbookAPI.getHttpRequest('POST', '/send_check');

        Map<String,Object> mapParams = new Map<String,Object>();
        mapParams.put('email', email);
        mapParams.put('amount', amount);
        mapParams.put('first_name', firstName);
        mapParams.put('last_name', lastName);
        mapParams.put('sender_email', semail);
        mapParams.put('description', description);
        req.setBody(JSON.serialize(mapParams));
        return CheckbookAPI.getHttpResponse(req);
    }


    private static String getHttpResponse(HttpRequest req) {
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
        return response.getBody();
    }

    private static HttpRequest getHttpRequest(String Method, String Path) {
        // Initialize the request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        // Build the selected elements
        String SelectedElements = '';


        // Set the method
        req.setMethod(Method);
        SelectedElements += Method;

        // Set the Content-Type header
        if (Method == 'POST') {
            SelectedElements += 'application/json';
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        }

        // Set the endpoint
        String CompletePath = '/' + CheckbookAPI.Config.DigitalCheck__VersionAPI__c + Path;
        SelectedElements += CompletePath;
        req.setEndpoint(CheckbookAPI.Config.DigitalCheck__ServerURL__c + CompletePath);

        return req;
    }



}
```

**API CALL class** :

```
global with sharing class DigitalChecksChargeController {

    public DigitalChecksChargeController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {

    }    

    @RemoteAction
    public static String processCharge() {
        return '200'; // Simulate the status code of the <charge> request
    }

    @RemoteAction
    public static String createCheck(String email, Decimal amount, String firstName, String lastName, String semail, String description) {    
        return CheckbookAPI.createCheck(email, amount, firstName, lastName, semail, description);
    }    
}
```

**TEST class:**

```
@isTest
public class CheckbookAPI_UsingStaticResources {
    public testmethod static void testWS() {
        String testBody = 'This is a test :-)';

        StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
        mock.setStaticResource('Test_WS');
        mock.setStatusCode(200);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        CheckbookAPI  callout = new CheckbookAPI ();
        HttpResponse resp = callout.getChecks();  // <== GETTING ERROR : Static methods cannot be invoked through an object instance: getChecks()

        //System.assertEquals(200, resp.getStatusCode());        
        //System.assertEquals(resp.getBody(), testBody);
    }
}
```

So I'm getting

```
Static methods cannot be invoked through an object instance: getChecks()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define your method as static you can call it directly without having to create an instance of your class. So instead of

```
CheckbookAPI  callout = new CheckbookAPI ();
HttpResponse resp = callout.getChecks();
```

You can do:

```
String resp = CheckbookAPI.getChecks();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now : Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from String to System.HttpResponse at line 11 column 14

Comment: Edited the answer. Did not see that your method returns a `String` and not `HttpResponse` object. By the way this is something fundamental when it comes to programming. I strongly suggest you start reading upon some documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to instantiate a class if you are to call a static method.

instead of

```
CheckbookAPI  callout = new CheckbookAPI ();
HttpResponse resp = callout.getChecks();
```

try using

```
HttpResponse resp = CheckbookAPI.getChecks();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now : Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from String to System.HttpResponse at line 11 column 14